# How to set Xcode font Alternative Stylistic Sets?

Tags: xcode, font

I'm trying to set stylistic sets (specifically for [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki/How-to-enable-stylistic-sets)'s `<=` ligature), but I can't apply alternative stylistic sets. I enable it in Xcode Preferences -> Fonts and select all options (or select them individually) -> Fonts -> Typography and enable the Alternative Stylistic Sets I want, but they don't get applied. Quitting and restarting Xcode and checking settings shows that they have been reset.

Pic of them enabled (but not applied, see red circle): [image: enabled but not applied]

Comment: The question borders on off-topicality here.  But questions about using IDEs for writing computer programs are definitely on topic over at SO, and this question might attract more, and more knowledgeable, users of Xcode over there.

Comment: What is the version of your Xcode? Mine is 11.3.1 and could not find out "Typography".

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I think it's more relevant to here than SO, in "What topics can I ask about here?" it says "We do encourage ... as well as _how to use tools like Xcode for non-language specific tasks_." My question is not about using Xcode for language specific tasks, but about styling Xcode

Comment: @Yoan When you're in the font view, click on the settings icon (top left) and then Typography

Comment: See this: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/wiki - you don't need to enable alternative stylistic sets for Xcode unless the version is <8.0.

Comment: @Yoan I already have ligatures on, I want to enable [specific alternative stylistic sets](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode/blob/master/showcases/v3/stylistic_sets.png)

Comment: These are separate items in Typography, e.g Traditional ampersand just wait to be checked - I can see it on your picture is unchecked.

Comment: @Yoan I understand that not every one is on, I am saying that regardless of what I toggle, they don't apply

Comment: Which one does not apply? and in what circumstances ?

Comment: @Yoan None of them ever apply: https://i.imgur.com/aatXNoH.png and https://i.imgur.com/dxaZ2RB.png

Comment: A new Fira Code release here: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode - I think the previous one had some bugs.

Comment: Just stumbled upon this exact problem now. The Alternative Stylistic Sets never get applied in Xcode. I'm using the latest version of Fira Code as of February of 2022, v6.2. I don't know whether this is Xcode's or Fira Code's fault. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I think it is more an Xcode problem than a font one. It does not work with any font I tried – FiraCode, MonoLisa, Pragmata Pro…